# log4net - Missing logs

Tags: log4net

We're using log4net in a number of our services.  Most of the time it works flawlessly.  However, we'll occasionally see log4net "freezes" for a period of time before continuing to work normally.  For example, the logs below shows that log4net was "frozen" for over 4 hours.  We know this application is verbose, so we expect to see logs written every second.

```
2010-11-04 04:02:09,393 DEBUG Some message...
2010-11-04 08:48:07,114 DEBUG Some other message...
```

Another problem we'll occasionally see is that entire log files get deleted.  We have log4net configured to roll over by date.  Sometimes we'll see that an entire weeks worth of logs go missing.  Is log4net mistakenly deleting these logs files?  We do not have log4net configured to keep a number of logs.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: nope.I think it is far more likely to be either your code, or something in your environment at fault.

Comment: We considered that something may be wrong with the environment, but we have multiple services installed on the same machine and they continue to log normally.

Comment: I am seeing log files go missing as well. Weeks will go by with no issue followed by several days of logs missing. My theory is that the roll to new file operation fails and doesn't recover, possibly that the system blocked the creation of the new .log123456789 file. Maybe A/V, maybe the folder is locked down too tight... not sure why this would result in intermittent issues like I am experiencing and you described. I see nothing in the event viewer.

Comment: @nivlam we have a similar issue, did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen this, but remember that Log4net is designed to continue even if it can not log its information - [See this FAQ Article](http://log4net.sourceforge.net/release/1.2.0.30316/doc/manual/faq.html#reliable)

If anything locks the log file (eg Backup/AntiVirus) then you will get missing information.

You could trying running [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) to see if any such warning appears when the logging fails or perhaps configure log4net to keep its own logs (see [another FAQ Article](http://log4net.sourceforge.net/release/1.2.0.30316/doc/manual/faq.html#internalDebug) )